# Is there a way to round an Oracle crosstab PIVOT?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I want to pivot data using the `AVG()` function, but I want to round the results to prevent repeating decimals from displaying.

When I try something like this: `PIVOT( ROUND( AVG(column_name), 2) FOR ...)`

I get an error: `ORA-56902: expect aggregate function inside pivot operation`

Here is a very simple example of "number of students registered in a course":

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_EXAMPLE
(
  enrolled NUMBER,
  course   VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
);

INSERT INTO TBL_EXAMPLE (enrolled, course) VALUES (1, 'math');
INSERT INTO TBL_EXAMPLE (enrolled, course) VALUES (2, 'math');
INSERT INTO TBL_EXAMPLE (enrolled, course) VALUES (2, 'math');
INSERT INTO TBL_EXAMPLE (enrolled, course) VALUES (1, 'english');
INSERT INTO TBL_EXAMPLE (enrolled, course) VALUES (4, 'english');

SELECT * 
  FROM TBL_EXAMPLE 
 PIVOT ( AVG(enrolled) FOR course IN ('math', 'english') );

'math'          'english'
---------------|-------------
1.6666666666...| 2.5
```

What I want is:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TBL_EXAMPLE 
 PIVOT ( ROUND(AVG(enrolled), 2) FOR course IN ('math', 'english') );

'math'          'english'
---------------|-------------
1.67           | 2.50
```

In the real world application, the SQL is being dynamically generated based on user input on a report, and due to the complexities of the real world scenario I can't just re-write the query like this:

```
SELECT ROUND("'math'", 2) as "'math'", ROUND("'english'", 2) as "'english'"
  FROM TBL_EXAMPLE 
 PIVOT ( AVG(enrolled) FOR course IN ('math', 'english') );
```

So, my question is, is there any workaround I can use to bypass `ORA-56902` in this scenario, or any other way to 'trick' Oracle into *NOT* returning up to 38 digits of decimal precision when numbers don't divide evenly via the `AVG()` calculation in a `PIVOT` clause?

Comment: use an inline view and then round?

Comment: @OldProgrammer not really an option since I really don't know how many columns will be returned or what the names of all the columns will be.

Comment: You are correct.  interesting problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why not perform the `AVG()` in a subquery with a `ROUND` and then apply your PIVOT:

```
select *
from
(
  select round(avg(enrolled), 2) enrolled, course
  from tbl_example
  group by course
) d
PIVOT 
( 
  max(enrolled) 
  FOR course IN ('math', 'english') 
);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3cf8c/5)